# when do you say "here you come"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I happened to see this expression "California, Here You Come"  in the article below.
But I don't know exactly what it means or under what situation you native English 
speakers say it. 
whole story:http://www.sunset.com/travel/california/california-here-you-come

Comment: I think it exploits the ambiguity of whether it is addressing visitors (as a state's slogan generally would) or California itself. In the first interpretation, visitors are bound to come to California because it is such an attractive place. In the second interpretation, California is addressed in a way that indicates that it is an up-and-coming place. The two interpretations together say "you're bound to come here because we're coming up in the world."

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult one because it is meant to convey the idea of "You" meaning "I" - "*California here I come*" which is a through back to the Gold Rush days of the 1840's

In this situation the article does sound grammatically incorrect, but I think the point is that the idea is to push the object on "You" as someone visiting California and not "I".

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when someone goes on vacation, they express their excitement by stating "California, here I come!" I think this goes back to the days of the gold rush, when people decided to head to California to make their fortune. Al Jolson has a song with the same title.

I read your article, and I didn't really get the reversal in the title. I guess she's referring to everything California has to offer her visitors.

Answer (score 0):

This headline is **not** meant to be an example of good English.

The author is daring the reader to visit California.  As mentioned in the other answers, "California, here I come!" is an old saying.  The headline writer is making a pun on the old saying.

If you do visit California in the near future, the headline will become a prophesy.